# Firing J-Script onClick event not working, IE Browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, watin

I have a question about WatiN, I just started using it today, and I can't figure out how to click a js button, here's what I got:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUser.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPass.Text))
    {
        browser.TextField("Username").Value = (txtUser.Text);
        browser.TextField("Password").Value = (txtPass.Text);
        var loginButton = browser.Form(Find.ById("loginForm")).Div(Find.ById("signInButtonPanel"));
        loginButton.Click(); //does nothing
        loginButton.FireEvent("onclick"); //does nothing
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
                    <div id="signInButtonPanel" data-use-apiproxy-signin="False" data-sign-on-api-path="https://api.roblox.com/login/v1">
                        <a  roblox-js-onclick class="btn-medium btn-neutral">Sign In</a>
                        <a  roblox-js-oncancel class="btn-medium btn-negative">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
```

Everything but the clicking part works, it can find the Div correctly, but I can't click it. I tried researching a lot of things to try to fix my problem, but I yet to find an answer.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be clicking on the "Sign In" link not the form itself. Try this code instead:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUser.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPass.Text))
    {
        browser.TextField("Username").Value = (txtUser.Text);
        browser.TextField("Password").Value = (txtPass.Text);
        var loginButton = browser.Div(Find.ById("signInButtonPanel"));
        loginButton.Links[0].Click(); // Try 0 or 1.
    }
}
```